# pandas get first element of contigous values to perform sessionization i.e. obtain the sesion start event

Tags: python, pandas

How can I find the first element of one of the sessions (for each group) which starts a new series of continuous values?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,], 'value':[
    1,2,3,4,5,10,11, 15, 16,17,18,19,20, # 13
    21, 22,23,24,26,27.28,
    4,5,6, 8,9,10,11,12, 13,14
]})
display(df)
```

so far I am stuck here:

```
df['shifted_value'] = df['value'].shift(-1)
df['difference_nect'] = df['shifted_value'] - df['value']

# this is obviously not yet correct - how can I get the first element (elemnt of 0 for each of the starting sessions)
df['session_element_index'] = df.groupby(['group']).cumcount()
df.head()
```

In SQL I would use a window function and compare previous/next elements to determine if a session starts/ends. Is there a nicer more pandas native way how to do this in a vectorized way?

Comment: Can you post the expected output for your example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with compare not equal `1` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('group')['value'].diff().ne(1)]
print (df1)
    group  value
0       1   1.00
5       1  10.00
7       1  15.00
17      1  26.00
18      1  27.28
19      2   4.00
22      2   8.00
```

If need counter column:

```
g = df.groupby('group')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().ne(1).cumsum())
df['session_element_index'] = df.groupby(g).cumcount()
print (df.head(10))
   group  value  session_element_index
0      1    1.0                      0
1      1    2.0                      1
2      1    3.0                      2
3      1    4.0                      3
4      1    5.0                      4
5      1   10.0                      0
6      1   11.0                      1
7      1   15.0                      0
8      1   16.0                      1
9      1   17.0                      2
```

Answer (score 0):

As the first approach:

```py
out = df.groupby("group", as_index=False).value \
        .apply(lambda s: ((s - s.shift()) != 1.0).cumsum() \
        .drop_duplicates())
```

```py
>>> out
0  0     1
   5     2
   7     3
   17    4
   18    5
1  19    1
   22    2
Name: value, dtype: int64

>>> out.index.get_level_values(1)
Int64Index([0, 5, 7, 17, 18, 19, 22], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: would also work - but is not as vectorized and elegant  as the first solution